# Contacts sync iCloud/iPhone/Mac after clean OS X install

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-synchronization, contacts

I have an clean Yosemite installation without any data transfer from an old mac.

My iCloud account is synced with my iPhone, and the mac is using the same iCloud account.

After a sync some contacts are not synced.

When I logging into www.icloud.com via the browser, i see all my contacts in my iCloud's address book. Here are 3 groups.

- mobile contacts
- all contacts
- wgroup

All 3 groups are synced with my iPhone but  didn't get synced the "mobile contacts" group nor the "wgroup" on the Mac. (The Mac didn't shows the groups).

Want achieve the following:

- get synced all contacts and all groups on my all devices.

Sounds simple, but

- where to setup what groups should be synced on Mac
- or how to move all contacts into single group?

Ps: ofcourse, i can send by email the vCards to Mac but this isn't the right solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with certain contacts and contact groups not coming back from iCloud after a clean Yosemite install.

Today I found out that all this contact groups and contacts are starting to sync once I edited them, e.g. add a contact to a group, update a contacts phone number. For me it worked to edit them in icloud.com (webpage) or on an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

While @Ralf solution is working, editing 300+ unsynced contacts isn't an easy job.  So, because the iCould and IOS are in sync and contains all contacts, only the Mac contacts are unsynced i solved it as following:

1. selected all contacts in the iCould web app (click the cog at left bottom)
2. again via the "cog" clicked `Export vCard...` (the Safari downloaded an `.vcf` file with all contacts.
3. Again `Select All` and `Delete` - so, deleted all my contacts via the iCould, so this erased all my contacts from the iPhone too.
4. Cleaned up all groups, in the iCloud.
5. Started `Contacts.app` in the Mac
6. Deleted all groups and all remaining contacts.
7. and finally dropped into the Mac's `Contacts.app` the downloaded file and imported all previously exported contacts.

In this way I got all contacts in sync with iCloud, iPhone and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

same issue and quite discouraged by the idea to edit 390 contacts.

I started the procedure suggested by m666, exporting my the contacts from iCloud.

As soon as the file has been created, voilà, something triggered contacts.app that asked the confirmation to import these 390 items, synching iCloud and Contacts.

I hope this will work for others...

Answer (score 0):

I found a different approach worked for the same problem.  By going in to iCloud contacts and editing each group name ( I did this by adding three semi colons after the group name) hitting enter and then going back in and removing the semi colons and hitting enter again the groups appeared in the contacts app on my iMac......Go figure!